# O gcov testa cobertura de código durante compilação ou durante execução?

Tags: c

Li sobre o gcov pela primeira vez [na documentação do Tor](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob_plain/master:/doc/HACKING), que diz:

```
'-' before a line means
that the compiler generated no code for that line.  '######' means that the
line was never reached.  Lines with numbers were called that number of times.
```

Não existe exatamente uma suíte de testes do Tor e, pela descrição acima, parece que o gcov testa cobertura de linhas durante a compilação.

Outras referências que achei sobre o gcov dão a entender que ele é usado para detectar que linhas foram atingidas *durante a execução* (seja durante uso normal ou por uma suíte de tests). Mas não deixam isso muito claro. Qual é, afinal de contas, a função do gcov?

Answer (score 1):

O gcov funciona usando **instrumentalização** do código. Por exemplo: para verificar quais funções são chamadas, ele adiciona código no início de todas as funções para salvar o nome da própria função em um arquivo. O mesmo se aplica para qualquer outra medição que queira fazer. No momento da execução do código você vai obter uma lista de todas as funções chamadas no arquivo.

É feito assim por que muitas análises são muito difíceis ou mesmo impossíveis de se realizar estaticamente (sem executar o código). Em particular por conta do *halting problem*, qualquer análise desse tipo será limitada de alguma forma. E no caso particular do gcov, ele quer localizar partes do código que nunca são executadas. Isso é altamente dependente do input dado no runtime. Análises estáticas podem dividir o código em três grupos apenas: *certamente será executado*, *nunca será executado* e *talvez seja executado*. O último grupo pode ser eliminado em runtime.

Comment: Entendi a diferença entre o que é possível entre verificação de cobertura em runtime vs estaticamente, mas qual dos dois o gcov faz?